# form select option required

Tags: forms, required

I am trying to make the select make and select model be required in this form.
Is it possible while its in a frorm?

```
    <form method="post" lpformnum="1">
      <select id="manufacturer_id" name="manufacturer_id">
        <option value="">Select Make</option>
      </select>
      <select name="model_id" id="model_id">
        <option value="">Select Model</option>
      </select>

      <div id="api_btn_deletethistohidebtn">
        <button type="button" id="api_search">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the '**required**' tag of the select field as seen in the example below.  This is something in HTML5.

```
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp

Edit: Alternatively, you can also use JS to validate the form data with far more control.

Comment: With it being an a form for some reason it wont see that there isnt an option selected

Comment: Good to hear, I'm glad i was able to help out :)